# Why does netsniff.js print javascript errors into the output?

Tags: javascript, parsing, error-handling, phantomjs, har

I use the netsniff.js like this:

```
phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any netsniff.js http://thermex.ru/ > t.out
```

When netsniff is done, I open file t.out in my text editor and I see the JS bugs like this:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating   '$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    mode: 'fade',
    preloadImages: 'all',
    slideWidth: 697
})')

http://thermex.ru/:565
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js:2
```

after this errors I see valid HAR data.

But I don't can parse this file, because him contains no valid JSON data (JS errors + valid JSON HAR data = no valid JSON data).

How can I receive the valid file from netsniff.js for this domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can register to the [`page.onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-error.html), [`page.onConsoleMessage`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-console-message.html) and [`phantom.onError`](http://phantomjs.org/api/phantom/handler/on-error.html) events to prevent the default action (before `page.open` in netsniff.js):

```
page.onError = function(){};
page.onConsoleMessage= function(){};
phantom.onError = function(){};
```